# How to update a Cygwin package that has no maintainer?

Tags: cygwin

Many Cygwin's packages have no maintainer, is it still revelant to use Cygwin ?

I would like to update ruby or ansible package to the last version, how can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am an end user. Not a lot of developpement knowledge. I used to use application like ansible or ruby from Cygwin. But those applications are not updated for some time. Using Cygport to update them is out of my reach.

Answer (score 1):

Package maintainers are volunteers.
Anyone can offer him/herself for the job.

Documentation
https://cygwin.com/packaging-contributors-guide.html

Mailing list for discussion about Maintainers
https://cygwin.com/mailman/listinfo/cygwin-apps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a maintainer you **must** subscribe to the Cygwin mailing lists. All discussions about maintaining packages are there, and you will be required to post your credentials (i.e. public key) there in order to upload updated packages. Note that some orphan packages became so because the previous maintainer needed to reduce their workload.

Once you are subscribed, just ask to take over an orphaned package, upload your credentials, install the source package, make necessary changes, and upload the new package. It sounds easy, but you might want to build the package and make sure it runs all tests before asking to be the new maintainer.

Note that there may be others who have tried to update a package, and encountered blocking problems. Those will be discussed in the mailing lists, which you can search.